# renaming columns of a pd.DataFrame using np.arange or something else within pd.<function> to assign alphabets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm using python 3.9. My pd.DataFrame has 11 columns which are numbered as (by default)

Col names -->   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

Can I use np.arange or pd.array() or someother function within pandas to assign/change the column names to alphabets?

I know long solution is :
df = pd.DataFrame(input_data,columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K'])

I was wondering if some function/method like columns=np.arange('A','J') would be possible. From running this code I learned arange can only handle int and floats not strings. Is there any object function that can accomplish this?

BRgds,

Comment: Both solutions below worked wonderful. Many Thanks to both Michael and Rodalm! Unfortunately, I can only click only one as "this answer solves my problem", so not clicking any as I like both solutions. Wish I could click both.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad I could help! Although you can only [mark as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one answer, you can [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) as many as you like. Accepting an answer is encouraged since informs others that your issue is resolved, which may help them if they have similar problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string.ascii_uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as ABC
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = list(ABC)[:len(df.columns)]

# >>> ABC
# 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Comment: Awesome Rodalm!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

input_data = np.random.random((100, 11))
cols = [chr(65 + c) for c in range(input_data.shape[1])]
df = pd.DataFrame(input_data, columns=cols)
print(df)
```

prints

| index | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.9754801564654546 | 0.9803147001267726 | 0.7301867551168492 | 0.34014130872203274 | 0.9030310266294121 | 0.019942427424042175 | 0.8876547248004468 | 0.7566170681794626 | 0.7544506461801366 | 0.8322020013684206 | 0.3540067814406911 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Explanation: `chr(i)` returns the character corresponding to the `i`-th unicode, and `'A'` is the 65-th (i.e. `(65 + 0)th`) unicode, `'B'` the 66-th (i.e. `(65 + 1)th`), etc.

Comment: Many Thanks Mike, it worked. One issue, using Jupyter, it works only once. I'm running dataframe creation and column rename in two separate cells. I can run dataframe creation followed by renaming columns and it will work for once. Guess I've to have both dataframe creation and rename run together. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9972\3795268622.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
----> 1 df.rename(columns={c: chr(65 + c) for c in df.columns}, inplace=True)
      2 df

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Many Thanks for explaining the key logic Mike, I stumbled to make sense of the logic. Now, I know it better than before.